# Updating several rows in table with different values

Tags: mysql

I got two tables:

TableA has two col: "AnswerId", "Date".
TableB has two col: "Id", "OldDate".

This is what I got so far:

```
update TableA
set TableA.Date = TableB.OldDate
where TableA.AnswerId = TableB.Id
```

But this only updates one row. How do I update all the rows in TableA with the correlating value from TableB? I dont really want to do it manually per row as I have several thousand rows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have no idea how your query could possibly work, because `tableB` is not defined.

You can use an explicit `join`:

```
update TableA a join
       TableB b
       on a.AnswerId = b.Id
    set a.Date = b.OldDate;
```

Comment: Thank you sir. This solved my problem. Could I marry you?